# How to access Shared Preferences data saved by flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences

I have saved some `SharedPreferences` data using flutter like so:

```
SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
   prefs.setString("my_data", "some data");
});
```

and also I'm createing a MethodChannel to do something using android and I want to access the SharedPreferences I have already created with flutter but I don't know how !
in android we can access `SharedPreferences` by specifying a name to the it like so:

```
getSharedPreferences("name");
```

But in flutter I don't sepcify a name I just call `SharedPreferences.getInstance()`